# Make one HTML element appear on top of the other when they are in the reverse order in source code

Tags: html, css, user-interface, formatting, html-lists

I am using list to render tabs in my WebUI. My approach requires me to place LABEL element before DIV.

LABEL is used to display tab name and DIV it's content.

I'm trying to visually display tabs at the bottom and content on the top (i.e. have bottom tabs)

My css/html looks like:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
label {
    padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
    font-size: .8em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
div {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
   <label>Tab Name 1</label>
   <div>Content for tab 1</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how do I achieve such effect?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the layout you are trying to achieve? When you say "tabs", do you mean a tabbed display but with the tabs on the bottom? Also, can you show us what the HML will look like with additional tabs? (Usually in a tabbed display the tab names are all together first, and then the divs are all together after this). An example or illustration would really help.

Comment: You can use flex for li and order or column reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:relative`, you can re-arrange the elements. This will only work responsively if you have pre-defined heights. The code below works for pre-defined heights will CSS.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
}
label {
    padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
    font-size: .8em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    top: 20px;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
   <label>Tab Name 1</label>
   <div>Content for tab 1</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you are not sure about the heights of the lists, consider using JavaScript to set the `top`, and `height` properties for the elements when the page loads using the `onload` event listener.